# Cannot use threads to insert data to PostgreSQL with DBIish. What's going wrong?

Tags: raku

Edit: This was solved by moritz. I've added a note to the code on the line that's wrong.

My application is a web server talking to a game client. The server is multithreaded, which Postgres allows. When loading client data into the database, I noticed parallel requests fail with several different errors, none of which make sense to me.

This short-ish test case dumps a nested hash into the database. When run without `start`, it works perfectly. When run with threads, it almost always gives one or more of the following errors:

> DBDish::Pg: Error:  (7)   in method prepare at
>   D:\rakudo\share\perl6\site\sources\BAD7C1548F63C7AA7BC86BEDDA0F7BD185E141AD
>   (DBDish::Pg::Connection) line 48   in block  at testcase.p6 line 62
>   in sub add-enum-mappings at testcase.p6 line 59   in block  at
>   testcase.p6 line 91
>
> DBDish::Pg: Error: ERROR:  prepared statement
>   "pg_3448_16" already exists  (7)   in method prepare at
>   D:\rakudo\share\perl6\site\sources\BAD7C1548F63C7AA7BC86BEDDA0F7BD185E141AD
>   (DBDish::Pg::Connection) line 46   in block  at testcase.p6 line 62
>   in sub add-enum-mappings at testcase.p6 line 59   in block  at
>   testcase.p6 line 91
>
> DBDish::Pg: Error: Wrong number of arguments to
>   method execute: got 1, expected 0 (-1)   in method enter-execute at
>   D:\rakudo\share\perl6\site\sources\65FFB78EFA3030486D1C4D339882A410E3C94AD2
>   (DBDish::StatementHandle) line 40   in method execute at
>   D:\rakudo\share\perl6\site\sources\B3190B6E6B1AA764F7521B490408245094C6AA87
>   (DBDish::Pg::StatementHandle) line 52   in sub add-enum-mappings at
>   testcase.p6 line 54   in block  at testcase.p6 line 90
>
> message type 0x31 arrived from server while idle
>   message type 0x5a arrived from server while idle
>   message type 0x74 arrived from server while idle
>   message type 0x6e arrived from server while idle
>   message type 0x5a arrived from server while idle

Here's the code. (If you choose to run it, remember to set the right password. It creates/manipulates a table called "enummappings", but does nothing else.) The meat is in `add-enum-mappings()`. Everything else is just setup. Oh, and `dbh()` creates a separate DB connection for each thread. This is necessary, according to the PostgreSQL docs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

use DBIish;
use Log::Async;

my Lock $db-lock;
my Lock $deletion-lock;
my Lock $insertion-lock;

INIT {
    logger.send-to($*ERR);
    $db-lock .= new;
    $deletion-lock .= new;
    $insertion-lock .= new;
}

# Get a per-thread database connection.
sub dbh() {
    state %connections;
    my $dbh := %connections<$*THREAD.id>; # THIS IS WRONG. Should be %connections{$*THREAD.id}.
    $db-lock.protect: {
        if !$dbh.defined {
            $dbh = DBIish.connect('Pg', :host<127.0.0.1>, :port(5432), :database<postgres>,
                :user<postgres>, :password<PASSWORD>);
        }
    };

    return $dbh;
}

sub create-table() {
    my $name = 'enummappings';
    my $column-spec =
        'enumname TEXT NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL, value INTEGER NOT NULL, UNIQUE(enumname, name)';
    my $version = 1;
    my $sth = dbh.prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $name ($column-spec);");
    $sth.execute;

    # And add the version number to a version table:
    dbh.execute:
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableversions (name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, version INTEGER NOT NULL);";
    $sth = dbh.prepare:
        'INSERT INTO tableversions (name, version) VALUES (?, ?)
            ON CONFLICT (name)
                DO
                    UPDATE SET version = ?;';
    $sth.execute($name, $version, $version);
}

sub add-enum-mappings($enumname, @names, @values --> Hash) {
    $deletion-lock.protect: {
        my $sth = dbh.prepare('DELETE FROM enummappings WHERE enumname = ?;');
        $sth.execute($enumname);
    };

    my @rows = (^@names).map: -> $i {$enumname, @names[$i], @values[$i]};
    info "Inserting @rows.elems() rows...";
    $insertion-lock.protect: {
        my $sth = dbh.prepare('INSERT INTO enummappings (enumname,name,value) VALUES '~
            ('(?,?,?)' xx @rows.elems).join(',') ~ ';');
        $sth.execute(@rows>>.list.flat);
    };

    return %(status => 'okay');
}

# Create a bunch of long enums with random names, keys, and values.
sub create-enums(--> Hash[Hash]) {
    my @letters = ('a'..'z', 'A'..'Z').flat;
    my Hash %enums = ();
    for ^36 {
        my $key = @letters.pick(10).join;
        for ^45 {
            my $sub-key = @letters.pick(24).join;
            %enums{$key}{$sub-key} = (0..10).pick;
        }
    }
    return %enums;
}

sub MAIN() {
    create-table;

    await do for create-enums.kv -> $enum-name, %enum {
        start {
            add-enum-mappings($enum-name, %enum.keys, %enum.values);
            CATCH { default { note "Got error adding enum: " ~ .gist; } }
        };
    }
}
```

I'm on Windows 10, with a 8-core computer. I know I could insert the data single-threadedly, but what if the game gets a hundred connections at once? I need to fix this for good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect your problem is here:

```
my $dbh := %connections<$*THREAD.id>;
```

The `%hash<...>` syntax is only for literals. You really need to write `%connections{$*THREAD.id}`.

With your error in place, you have just one DB connection that's shared between all threads, and I guess that's what DBIish (or the underlying postgresql C client library) is unhappy about.